# class.getPackage().getSpecificationVersion() gives me a NullPointer tinyb

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to work with the Java bluetooth library tinyb and I have a spring boot project where I imported the tinyb library like that.

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openhab.osgiify/intel-iot-devkit.tinyb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openhab.osgiify</groupId>
            <artifactId>intel-iot-devkit.tinyb</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now when I want to use this [example](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb/blob/master/examples/java/HelloTinyB.java) program I keep getting a Nullpointer in the BluetoothManager.class

The Problem is, that BluetoothManager.class.getPackage().getSpecificationVersion(); returns Null.
This [issue](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb/issues/67) seems to have a similiar problem, though for me it happens when I run the program in Intellij via SSH on my raspberry pi

Would be grateful for any advise how to fix this :)

(this throws the Nullpointer for me at var1 = ...w)

```
    public static synchronized BluetoothManager getBluetoothManager() throws RuntimeException, BluetoothException {
        if (inst == null) {
            String var0 = getNativeAPIVersion();
            String var1 = BluetoothManager.class.getPackage().getSpecificationVersion();
            if (!var1.equals(var0)) {
                String[] var2 = var0.split("\\D");
```

Comment: You already found a bug, which is not marked as resolved or anything. I don't think there is anything you can do.